# How to convert jpeg or bmp image into Raw format

Tags: qt, terminal, applescript

I am trying to convert images from JPEG/BMP to raw file format(CR2,CEW,NEF,SR2,X3F,ORf,ARW,SRF) and QTIF , ICNS pro-grammatically in Qt or Apple script. So is there a library or method to do the same.
.and Sips terminal command do not convert JPEG file to QTIF file format.but sips command support a QTIF format.I am not understand ,why convert to QTIF file format.

Comment: There is no reason to convert to raw, usually images are converted from raw to another format. Raw stores the raw data that was captured on the sensor in a camera. When an image is processed, either by the camera itself or manually with a software package, it is common for the output to be saved to another format, such as Tiff or Jpeg. In this case, a lot of the data that was stored in the raw file is lost. Therefore, going back to raw has no value.

Comment: ok. tell me,how to convert raw format to another format(jpeg,bmp,png,tga,psd,pdf,tiff etc.).

Comment: As raw is a generic term with different formats depending on the camera manufacturer; there isn't a straight forward answer to that. However, if you really want to go there, here's C code that you can explore, which converts raw of different formats: http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/dcraw.c

Comment: ok.I am try to this class.If you are provide me sufficient answer please replay me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sips`(scriptable image processing system) command

> This tool is used to query or modify raster image files and ColorSync
>   ICC
>        profiles.  Its functionality can also be used through the "Image Events"
>        AppleScript suite.

Comment: please specify any example which convert jpeg to raw image format.

Comment: sips can convert raw image to jpeg. Not sure about jpeg to raw image

Comment: ok thanks for replay, Please tell me name of raw file format which convert to JPEG.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35562/discussion-between-user1705318-and-parag-bafna)

Comment: Thanks, I am successfully convert CR2 image to jpeg image (for canon camera ) . can you tell me ,How to convert Nikon and sony image into jpeg image.

Comment: thank you very much for your replay. and can you tell me how to convert QTIF and paint mac images into jpeg image.